# What European city is in this picture?

Tags: europe, where-on-earth, identify-this

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what city this is?

I know it's somewhere in Europe.

Comment: Looks like Genoa to me.

Comment: maybe is Vernazza (Cinque Terre) Italy

Comment: It is not Vernazza and seems too small to be Genoa for me. Given the few people in the background and the shade the pic seems to have been taken in the morning and the stony beach in the background thus facing roughly south. A better resolution picture would greatly help and also less of the image blacked out.

Comment: Why is a bit of the second image blanked out?

Comment: @CMaster Presumably because there's a person in it.

Comment: Given the characteristic green window blinds I would further guess that's Italy.

Comment: @mts also the church is very typical for cities in Northern Italy.

Comment: @JonathanReez I agree and, from what little that can be seen, it resembles waterfront town on one of the lakes.

Comment: I somehow doubt these are one of the northern lakes as I see little in the way of mountains but rather a hill and also guessing from the vegetation which is more adapted to heat, so this may be further south actually...

Comment: @JoerNano here's your chance to get some of your bounty back!

Answer (score 22):

The location is [here](https://www.google.it/maps/search/porticiolo+di+nervi/@44.3826292,9.0309251,17.25z) on google maps. The name is **Il porticciolo di Nervi**.

A page with an alternate image can be seen on [ilmeteo.it](http://www.ilmeteo.it/foto/Genova/id/4337556122). The location is near to Genoa.

[image]

How I found it.

I came to the same conclusion as @mts that it was South facing. It looked like nobody was around with the sun fairly low and shadows cast from the East. There was also a green sun blind on one of the high buildings that indicated South facing too. I spotted a satellite dish which was also another indication.

I then started looking around Italy for south facing bays but no luck. I went all the way up to Genoa and saw what looked like an image of the church tower in one of the google maps images. Bingo.

Comment: well done; I went searching along the Ligurian coast to the southwest of Genova while you followed the sun.

Comment: @Dorothy Was a great question. No clues in meta-data, no readable text anywhere, no hits on google images after slicing the images up.